# Getting the warning Served eth_sendRawTransaction err="already known" on local blockchain with metamask

Tags: transactions, metamask, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction

**The problem:** I call a smart contract function on my local blockchain, then I confirm the transaction on metamask and finally the transaction is submitted but the transaction does not get mined.

On the blockchain console I receive the warning below:

```
WARN [03-26|18:21:48.169] Served eth_sendRawTransaction            conn=127.0.0.1:60092 reqid=1559115320157 t=213.552µs   err="already known"
```

Instead, when I disable metamask and I send a transaction with the unloacked account then the transaction get mined.

The strange thing that it used to work, I made many operations since yesterday.

Do you have any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Try resetting MetaMask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Ismael for your comment after much time spent with this error I have found that this error occurs when I reset my local geth node to the genesis block without resetting the account in meta mask. Now every time I want to start back from genesis I go into Meta Mask Settings => Advanced => Reset Account. This has worked for me I hope this helps you!